# AngularJS only characters directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive that only accepts characters input in textbox which is A-Z and a-z. This is my directive:

```
  angApp.directive('onlyCharacters', function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                $(elem).keydown(function (e) {
                    if (!((e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) ||
                            e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 9)
                        ) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

This even works for small a-z. I am wondering how does that. Isn't ascii keys for lowercase A-Z is 97-122? However the above directive works for upper as well as lower case.

Please suggest how does the above code work for lower case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `keyup` and `keydown` are used to identify the physical keys pressed not the value which those keys correspond to. Compare the codes to the ones you get from the `keypress` event.

You'll see that you are correct with regard to the key ranges in `keypress` but both a and A are achieved by hitting the same physical key => same key code in `keyup` and `keydown`.